# How to add ArrayList<My class> in ArrayAdapter for spinner?

Tags: android, arraylist, spinner, android-arrayadapter

```
private ArrayAdapter spn_1;
ArrayList<My Class> result;
 spn_1 = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, result);

 spn_1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            m_spn_gender.setAdapter(spn_1);
```

I try like this but it wrong

what should I do?

Comment: why dont you go with defining custom adapter as you are having arraylist of objects of your class?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put objects in the `ArrayList`.